# update column of all rows of table

Tags: sql-server

I have 1 table with 500 rows, and another table with 750 rows or so. What I'm doing is, I'm getting a random 500 rows of a certain column from the second table, and I want to update a newly added column on the first table with those 500 values.

I know how to do updates that look like this:

```
UPDATE schema.table1
SET column = cl.column FROM schema.table1 cl
INNER JOIN table2 cf ON cf.column = cl.column
```

but I don't have any columns that are matching in both tables. Is there a way to do this without having to match the columns on the inner join?

so basically, I want to update 500 rows of 1 column in one table, with 500 values coming from another table

Comment: Is this MySql or SQL Server?  The answer will depend on which one you're using.

Comment: @MauriceReeves sql server management studio

Comment: So you don't have matching column but you want to use inner join . Tell us first why you want update without logic ?

Comment: There's no real reason to avoid the inner join if it works.  SQL Server allows for updates using joins, for this kind of case.  Why don't you want to use it?  Also, can you show us the table structures and some sample data?

Comment: @MauriceReeves I don't mind using it, just don't know how if the columns aren't in both tables. And Imran, why do you care why i want to update another table, its a requirement for work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using `ROW_NUMBER` to generate column to join two tables. take a look at the example and the output

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE ( column1 INT ,column2 VARCHAR(2) )

DECLARE @T2 TABLE ( column1 VARCHAR(2) )

INSERT INTO @T1 ( column1, column2 ) 
        VALUES  ( 0, 'A' ), ( 1, 'B' ), ( 2, 'C' )

INSERT INTO @T2 ( column1 ) 
    VALUES ( 'D'),( 'F'),( 'G' )


SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) ) AS RN FROM @T1
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) ) AS RN FROM @T2

;WITH CTE_1 AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) ) AS RN FROM @T1)
    ,cte_2 AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) ) AS RN FROM @T2)
UPDATE t1
SET t1.column2 = t2.column1
FROM CTE_1 t1
JOIN cte_2 t2
ON t1.rn = t2.rn

SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) ) AS RN FROM @T1
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) ) AS RN FROM @T2
```